# Hide toolbar in wordpress, including in back-end, including for admins

Tags: wordpress, toolbar, wordpress-4.0

I'm looking for a programmatically way to hide top toolbar, which displays for logged in users in WordPress.

I tried some things I found on different websites but nothing worked, like :

```
show_admin_bar(false);
```

or

```
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
```

Please note that I want to remove the toolbar on the front and the back end, including for admins.

Thanks for any advice !

NOTE : I'm using wordpress 4.0

Comment: Users > Your Profile > Untick "Show Toolbar when viewing site" for front end, why would this be necessary for admins? It has fairly vital buttons.

Comment: I'm working on a quite complex plugin that would modify the admin back-end, restructuring its menus, toolbars, etc. It might be a very specific need but it is essential to my plugin to remove this toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend hiding using CSS. You can use the filters to hide the admin bar for regular users, but you would need CSS for admins.

```
#wpadminbar {
 display:none;
}
```

or

```
.logged-in #wpadminbar {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: The hooks `wp_before_admin_bar_render`/`wp_after_admin_bar_render` will let you capture the output buffer. Still need some CSS to clean up the admin though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the action hooks `wp_before_admin_bar_render` and `wp_after_admin_bar_render` to trigger and end capturing the output buffer, which can just be tossed away since you aren't using it. The PHP functions [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [`ob_get_clean()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) can be used for this purpose. Note that the CSS on the admin will leave an empty spot where the bar used to be, adjust using custom CSS.

```
if ( is_admin() ){
    add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', function(){ ob_start(); } );
    add_action( 'wp_after_admin_bar_render', function(){ ob_get_clean(); } );
} else {
    show_admin_bar( false );
    add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
}
```

Comment: This works fine. I like this 'tricky' solution using buffers. And you're right, in both case (using buffers, or CSS) I will need to re-adjust content with CSS after.